# CAML Query on value ending with space

Tags: caml-query, caml

I have the following CAML query:

```
<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="Title" /><Value Type="Text">TestDocument </Value></Eq></Where>
```

I have an item in the list with Title "TestDocument" without the space at the end. The value I am querying has a space at the end so I expect to find nothing. When I execute I get the item without the space in the title.

I also tried using CDATA

```
<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="Title" /><Value Type="Text"><![CDATA[TestDocument ]]></Value></Eq></Where>
```

no luck

How can I make it so the space is actually part of the value parameter?

Comment: Tried with a encoded space (%20)? https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Comment: %20 doesn't work. I also tried _x0020_ that also doesn't work. For now I get the item and then compare item.Title to my input param. But I would like to do that with my query

Comment: Changing <Eq> to <Contains> or <BeginsWith> does use the space when querying. But this can give me other issues.